# How can I correctly showing a square image in a rectangle shaped view with Swift and XCode? Something similar to object-fit: cover in CSS?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swift5

In my project I have a rectangle shaped view but I am only loading square shaped images (Specifically album covers) into the view. An example would be [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgXps.jpg). When it is loaded into the view it becomes distorted like [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU3tY.jpg). I'm looking for the image to load as something like `object-fit: cover` in CSS. So the image would end up like [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw5m2.jpg). Where the greyed out parts are not shown in the actual view. So in a perfect world all I would have to do is `imageView.contentMode = .cover`. Let me know if anybody has any suggestions

Edit: the current distorted image in the view is using `imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill` and I've also tried `imageView.contentMode = .center, .scaleAspectFit, .scaleToFill` and had no luck

Answer (score 0):

Had `imageView.contentMode = .scaleToAspectFill` in the wrong spot... sorry everybody